# Problem with axes when I plot a function and a barplot in the same graph

Tags: r, plot

When I plot two graphs (a function and a barplot) I have a problem with axes.

[image: axes issue]

I have already tried to put 
    axes = FALSE.
Although it didn't work well ...

Here is my code :

```
n = 64
p = 0.5
tailleEchantillon<-1000
m = n * p
sigma = sqrt(n * p * (1 - p))
borne_sup = m+7*sigma
borne_inf = m-7*sigma

x = 0:n
echantillon = rbinom(tailleEchantillon,n,p)

tabEffectifs = NULL
for (i in x)  {tabEffectifs = c(tabEffectifs,length(echantillon[echantillon == i]))}


print("Tableau des effectifs")
print(table(echantillon,deparse.level=2))

texteLegende1<-bquote(p == .(p))
texteTitre1 = ""

barplot(tabEffectifs,las=1,names.arg=x,col="blue",ylim=c(0,(tailleEchantillon/4)),legend.text=texteLegende1,main=texteTitre1,xlab="k",ylab="Effectifs",cex.main=1)

tabFrequences = tabEffectifs/tailleEchantillon



plot(function(x) dnorm(x, m, sigma), borne_inf, borne_sup, legend.text="Courbe loi normale", ylim=c(0,0.10), xlab="x", ylab="prob")
par(new = T)
barplot(tabFrequences,las=1,names.arg=x, col="red", ylim=c(0,0.10),legend.text=texteLegende2,main=texteTitre2,xlab="k",ylab="Densites",cex.main=1)
```

Does someone know how I could avoid this problem with superimposing axes? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"` in the call to `plot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that normally the line have to follow the barplot and it is not true here. I don't uderstand why because in the normal law the maximum should be for x = m and in this m = 36 and not 25 ..

I think that the two (line and barplot) don't have the same x axe. Do you have any solution for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
barplot(tabFrequences,las=1,names.arg=x, col="red", ylim=c(0,0.10))
lines(x, dnorm(x,m, sigma), col ="blue")
```

This way you are only superimposing the line as opposed to the whole graph.

[image]

For full disclosure, I only answered your question about plotting. There seems to be something funky with the distribution. Maybe something wrong in your simulation?